# Please explain this e-mail validation regular expression:

Tags: javascript

I have this script uses regular expressions to check that a form field contains a valid email address.Please explain me from declare

```
var emailfilter=/^\w+[\+\.\w-]*@([\w-]+\.)*\w+[\w-]*\.([a-z]{2,4}|\d+)$/i;
```

Thank you

Source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Email Validation script- © Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice must stay intact for legal use.
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

var emailfilter=/^\w+[\+\.\w-]*@([\w-]+\.)*\w+[\w-]*\.([a-z]{2,4}|\d+)$/i

function checkmail(e){
var returnval=emailfilter.test(e.value)
if (returnval==false){
alert("Please enter a valid email address.")
e.select()
}
return returnval
}

</script>

<form>
<input name="myemail" type="text" style="width: 270px"> <input type="submit" onClick="return checkmail(this.form.myemail)" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`/^\w+[\+\.\w-]*@([\w-]+\.)*\w+[\w-]*\.([a-z]{2,4}|\d+)$/i`

`/` = Begin an expression
`^` = The matched string must begin here, and only begin here
`\w` = any word (letters, digits, underscores)
`+` = match previous expression at least once, unlimited number of times
`[]` = match any character inside the brackets, but only match one
`\+\.` = match a literal `+` or `.`
`\w` = another word
`-` = match a literal `-`
`*` = match the previous expression zero or infinite times
`@` = match a literal `@` symbol
`()` = make everything inside the parentheses a group (and make them referencable)
`[]` = another character set
`\w-` = match any word or a literal `-`
`+` = another `1 to infinity` quantifier
`\.` = match another literal `.`
`*` = another `0 to infinity` quantifier
`\w+` = match a word at least once
`[\w-]*\.` = match a word or a dash at least zero times, followed by a literal `.`
`()` = another group
`[a-z]{2,4}` = match lowercase letters at least 2 times but no more than 4 times
`|` = "or" (does not match pipe)
`\d+` = match at least 1 digit
`$` = the end of the string
`/` = end an expression
`i` = test the string in a case **i** nsensitive manner

Or you could try [this awesome link](https://encrypted.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=explain%20email%20validation%20regular%20expression&btnG=Google+Search).  You know, whatever.

Answer (score 3):

```
var emailfilter=/^\w+[\+\.\w-]*@([\w-]+\.)*\w+[\w-]*\.([a-z]{2,4}|\d+)$/i
```

is Regulare expression to test email addres.

Read about regurlare expression on wiki :- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 2):

emailfilter.test(e.value)

emailfilter is a regular expression against which the e.value that you entered in text field is getting tested.

If the passes the regex than the email is valid.

Answer (score 2):

There are several sites online that you can type a regex into and get an explanation for in words.  One of them is http://www.strfriend.com/.

EDIT: More viewers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772594/regular-expression-explained-with-words.

Answer (score 2):

This code is just checks validity of entered email addresses by given regular expression, if value is not valid - alert is shown to user.

If you are not really clear with Regualar Expressions, there are tons info on that:

http://www.google.com.ua/search?aq=1&oq=regula&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=regular+expression

Answer (score 2):

It's a **broken** test for valid RFC 5322 e-mail addresses.

It doesn't cope with quoted user parts, internationalised domain names, or TLDs that have more than 4 characters in them (e.g. `.museum`, `.travel`).

At the same time, it incorrectly permits domain name labels that have a leading or trailing `-` in them.

**DON'T USE IT!**